# How to handle empty event in Spring reactor

Tags: spring, project-reactor

Well, this sounds counter-intuitive to what reactive programming is, but I am unable to comprehend a way to handle nulls/exceptions.

```
private static class Data {
    public Mono<String> first() {
        return Mono.just("first");
    }
    public Mono<String> second() {
        return Mono.just("second");
    }

    public Mono<String> empty() {
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

I understand that fundamentally unless a publisher publishes an event, a subscriber will not act. So a code like this would work.

```
Data data = new Data();
data.first()
    .subscribe(string -> Assertions.assertThat(string).isEqualTo("first"));
```

And if the first call returns empty, I can do this.

```
Data data = new Data();
data.empty()
    .switchIfEmpty(data.second())
    .subscribe(string -> Assertions.assertThat(string).isEqualTo("second"));
```

But how do I handle a case when both the calls return empty (typically this is an exception scenario that would need to be propagated to the user).

```
Data data = new Data();
data.empty()
    .switchIfEmpty(data.empty())
    .handle((string, sink) -> Objects.requireNonNull(string))
    .block();
```

The handle is not called in the above example since no event was published.

Comment: Not an expert, so I won't post this as an answer, but why not call switchIfEmpty() a second time, with a Mono.error() as argument, and then pass an error callback in subscribe() to handle the error?

Comment: Thanks! I believe that seems to be the best way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as JB Nizet pointed out, you can chain in a second `switchIfEmpty` with a `Mono.error`.

Or, if you're fine with a `NoSuchElementException`, you could chain in `single()`. It enforces a strong contract of *exactly one* element, otherwise propagating that standard exception.